# Using AutoHotkey, I'm trying to remap the function keys to their secondary function as default and the default as the secondary

Tags: autohotkey, function-keys

I'm trying to remap the function keys to their secondary function as a default nut I'm running into a few issued in the code. One thing to note is that, in my keyboard driver software, I can switch the `Fn` key to be a right windows key so I can avoid the low level coding issues involved with the `Fn` key.

I have written the following and the first bunch of hotkeys seem to work fine:

```
RightWindowsDown := 0

F1::Send {Volume_Mute}
F2::Send {Volume_Down}
F3::Send {Volume_Up}
F4::Send {Launch_App2}
F5::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
F6::Send {Media_Stop}
F7::Send {Media_Prev}
F8::Send {Media_Next}
F9::Send {Launch_App1}


RWin:: 
{
    RightWindowsDown:=1
    soundbeep
}

If (RightWindowsDown = 1)
{
    F1::F1
    F2::F2
    F3::F3
    F4::F4
    F5::F5
    F6::F6
    F7::F7
    F8::F8
    F9::F9
}

return
```

However, when I press the RWin key, it just spams the normal F1 key and opens up a load of help pages. Any ideas on how I can avoid this?

Comment: Pretty much all such keyboards have some way for an "FN Lock" to achieve this without any tools. Did you try that before?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works a little better.
I've included an #If directive. It tells AHK "Hey, only let these work if the #If directive returns true". When you hit F1-F9, it'll check to see if you're holding RWin first. If you are, it uses the alternate hotkey.

```
#SingleInstance, Force
return

F1::Send {Volume_Mute}
F2::Send {Volume_Down}
F3::Send {Volume_Up}
F4::Send {Launch_App2}
F5::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
F6::Send {Media_Stop}
F7::Send {Media_Prev}
F8::Send {Media_Next}
F9::Send {Launch_App1}

#If GetKeyState("RWin", "P")
F1::F1
F2::F2
F3::F3
F4::F4
F5::F5
F6::F6
F7::F7
F8::F8
F9::F9
```

---

References:
[#If](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)
[GetKeyState](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm)